# ReactJS state not defined even though I called bind()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created an event that gets called from a child.

When the event gets raised, though, this.state is undefined.

I even called bind! What is going on?

How do I access state from inside a function in a component raised by the child?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        showQuestion: false,
        showGetStarted: true,
        correctAnswerTotal: 0,
        question: <Question onAnswer={this.handleAnswer}/>,
        emoji: <EmojiView correctQuestionCount="100"/>
    };

    this.handleAnswer = this.handleAnswer.bind(this);
}

handleAnswer(result) {
    let emoji = this.state.emoji;       // error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emoji' of undefined  
    if (result === true) {
        emoji.props.correctAnswerTotal = emoji.props.correctAnswerTotal + 1;
    } else {
        emoji.props.correctAnswerTotal = 0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the requested part of Question component:

```
questionFourClicked = (user) => {
    let lastQuestion = this.state.lastQuestion;
    if (lastQuestion.correctIndex == 3) {
        // TODO: they got it right!
        var myQuestionModel = new QuestionModel("unused");
        let randomQuestion = myQuestionModel.getRandomQuestion();
        this.setState({lastQuestion: randomQuestion});
        this.props.onAnswer(true);
    } else {
        this.props.onAnswer(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full component code, you said functional component but this is a class based component? In either case, you create your Question sub component and pass this.handlerAnswer to if before you bind it to the context, so just switch the order of those two operations and it should work.

Comment: Perhaps you can try retrieving another state property to see if it returns undefined, or if its exclusive to this.state.emoji.

Comment: @MysteriousShadow: State is the part that is undefined. I tried referencing one (question) and it got the same undefined response.

Comment: @Milton : You totally solve my problem. I ALWAYS saw the binding at the END of the constructor in the examples. I would never have guessed to do that. Thanks. If you want to add it as the answer I'll get you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For visibility:
You create your Question sub component and pass `this.handlerAnswer` to it before you bind it to the context, so just switch the order of those two operations and it should work.